# 'return' with not-None expression list returns 'None'

Tags: python, return

I'm currently working on XML (SVG) traversing and have the next problem:
my function always return None after `if currNode.parentNode is rootNode:`, though, as you can see in the code below, I've explicitly set return to 'flag', which is non-empty string.
The most interesting part here is that `print('...')` prints three dots, so the problem is exactly there (or at least looks like that).

According to the Python docs: 'If an expression list is present, it is evaluated, else None is substituted.'

So, in short, the question is:
why 'return' doesn't returns 'flag' string, but 'None' instead?

Here's this piece of code:

`def relsLookup(currNode, rootNode):
    if currNode.nextSibling is not None:
        currNode = currNode.nextSibling
        return currNode
    elif currNode.nextSibling is None:
        if currNode.parentNode is rootNode:
            flag = 's2s_exception_end_of_svg'
            print('...')
            return flag
        elif currNode.parentNode.localName == 'g':
            if currNode.parentNode.nextSibling is not None:
                print('<--')
                currNode = currNode.parentNode.nextSibling
                return currNode
            elif currNode.parentNode.nextSibling is None:
                print('<--')
                currNode = currNode.parentNode
                relsLookup(currNode, rootNode)
        else:
            flag = 's2s_exception_unknown_parent'
            return flag
    else:
        flag = 's2s_exception_unknown_sibling'
        return flag`

Comment: And if `currNode.parentNode is not rootNode`?  What then?  Or `currNode.nextSibling is not None`?  What happens then?

Comment: Can you post the whole function? The important part is what happens if this `if` block is not entered.

Comment: The last 3 lines are dead code. A value is either None or not, there is no third possibility. Just write `if something is None: ... else: ...`

Comment: @a.reva: "It simply checks ..." it doesn't have a `return` statement under some circumstance.  Why is it missing a `return` under some circumstances?  Why is there a logic path that is missing a `return`?

Comment: @S.Lott: It simply checks whether parent node is a 'group' and if it is -- check whether it have siblings to make them active (i.e. currNode).

Comment: @a.reva: "It simply checks ..." is not what I'm asking.  Why is it missing a `return` under some circumstances? Why is there a logic path that is missing a `return`?  Please answer the question.

Comment: @a.reva: Please post the correct answer as an answer.  Other people are trying to learn from this.   Please remove the "looks like it was problem in another function" comment, since that doesn't help anyone.  Please provide the answer or close the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with the following part of your code:

```
        elif currNode.parentNode.nextSibling is None:
            print('<--')
            currNode = currNode.parentNode
            relsLookup(currNode, rootNode)
```

Did you mean to say:

```
        elif currNode.parentNode.nextSibling is None:
            print('<--')
            currNode = currNode.parentNode
            return relsLookup(currNode, rootNode)
```

?

Comment: Honestly? I'm noob to programming, so can't say exactly... Though I don't think it suppose to return anything. Just do recursion.

Comment: @a.reva: aix is right, you need a return there, else the first call to `relsLookup` returns `None` in this case.

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: the problem is that I've got errors in function that calling 'relsLookup' after adding return. In either case I'm missing something...

Comment: @a.reva: What exactly are the errors that you're getting? Are you sure you didn't mess up the indentation while editing the file?

Comment: & Jochen Ritzel: Ok, now I got it (haven't understood yours answers at first...)! Since I haven't specified `return` it returned `None`.
BTW, errors that I've got where caused by the checking the result in dict **item** rather then **index** (couldn't choose what is better: tuple or dict, and when changed message-checker to dict, by mistake leaved code with smth like this: `if msg in EXCEPTIONS:`).

Answer (score 2):

According to your listing, there is only one explanation: Either `currNode.nextSibling` isn't `None` or it is, but `currNode.parentNode is rootNode` is `False`. Set a default return statement at the end of the method / function to test this:

```
if currNode.nextSibling is None:
    if currNode.parentNode is rootNode:
        flag = 'end_of_svg'
        print('...')
        return flag
    return 'nested if failed'
return 'currNode.nextSibling is not None!!!'
```

Answer (score 2):

The core problem you are seeing is that a function which "falls off the end" (i.e. reaches the end of the code without returning a value or raising an exception) will implicitly return `None` to the caller.

Hence the suggestion from Daren to include an explicit return at the end to see what is happening and aix noting the recursive case where you don't actually return anything.

Given the structure of your code, the recursive case is currently broken, since it won't return a value.